# Custom post types saved as basic post

Tags: custom-post-types, save-post

I made a custom post type filters for others post types.
The slug is a concatenation like `"filters-" . $custom-post-type`.

And the custom post type appears correctly in the menu :

[image]

My problem is when I try to save one, it is saved with `post_type = post`.
What I missed up ?

This is my PHP Code :

```
class SearchFilters
{


    public $post_type_slug;
    public $post_type_label_name;
    public $post_type_singular_name;

    public $current_plugin_domain;

    public function __construct( $post_type_slug, $post_type_label_name, $post_type_singular_name )
    {
        $this->current_plugin_domain = get_current_plugin_domain();

        $this->post_type_slug = $post_type_slug;
        $this->post_type_label_name = $post_type_label_name;
        $this->post_type_singular_name = $post_type_singular_name;
        $this->init();
    }

    private function init(){
        $filters_slug = "filters-" . $this->post_type_slug;
        $filters_args = [
            'labels' => array(
                'name'          => sprintf( __( "Filters - Search Form for %s", $this->current_plugin_domain  ), $this->post_type_label_name   ),
                'singular_name' => __( "Filter", $this->current_plugin_domain  ),
                'menu_name'          => __( "Filters", $this->current_plugin_domain  ),
                'add_new_item'          => sprintf( __( "Filters - Add New Search Form for %s", $this->current_plugin_domain  ), $this->post_type_singular_name  )
            ),
            'description' => __( "Filters to display search form on front end", $this->current_plugin_domain ),
            'supports' => array( 'title' ),
            'public' => false,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'show_in_menu' => "edit.php?post_type=" . $this->post_type_slug,
            'auto_save' => false
        ];
        $result_filter = register_post_type(
            $filters_slug,
            $filters_args
        );
        if ( is_wp_error( $result_filter ) ) {
            wp_error_log( $result_filter->get_error_message(), "Filter Post type creation " . "[" . __CLASS__ . "]" );
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: How are you calling the class to register "Properties" ?

Comment: "Properties" works perfectly. I´m using register_post_type to declare as well.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code :

```
class SearchFilters
{


    public $post_type_slug;
    public $post_type_label_name;
    public $post_type_singular_name;

    public $current_plugin_domain;

    public function __construct( $post_type_slug, $post_type_label_name, $post_type_singular_name )
    {
        $this->current_plugin_domain = get_current_plugin_domain();

        $this->post_type_slug = $post_type_slug;
        $this->post_type_label_name = $post_type_label_name;
        $this->post_type_singular_name = $post_type_singular_name;
        $this->init();
    }

    private function init(){
        $filters_slug = "filters-" . $this->post_type_slug;
        $filters_args = [
            'labels' => array(
                'name'          => sprintf( __( "Filters - Search Form for %s", $this->current_plugin_domain  ), $this->post_type_label_name   ),
                'singular_name' => __( "Filter", $this->current_plugin_domain  ),
                'menu_name'          => __( "Filters", $this->current_plugin_domain  ),
                'add_new_item'          => sprintf( __( "Filters - Add New Search Form for %s", $this->current_plugin_domain  ), $this->post_type_singular_name  )
            ),
            'description' => __( "Filters to display search form on front end", $this->current_plugin_domain ),
            'supports' => array( 'title' ),
            'public' => false,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'exclude_from_search' => true,
            'show_in_admin_bar'   => false,
            'show_in_nav_menus'   => false,
            'publicly_queryable'  => false,
            'query_var'           => false,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-tag',
            'capability_type' => 'post',
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => $this->post_type_slug),
            'show_in_menu' => "edit.php?post_type=" . $this->post_type_slug,
            'auto_save' => false
        ];
        $result_filter = register_post_type(
            $filters_slug,
            $filters_args
        );
        if ( is_wp_error( $result_filter ) ) {
            wp_error_log( $result_filter->get_error_message(), "Filter Post type creation " . "[" . __CLASS__ . "]" );
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `rewrite` is wrong and `menu_icon` is not useful but I will test adding `exclude_from_search`, `show_in_admin_bar`, `show_in_nav_menus`, `publicly_queryable` and `query_var`

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be link to a jQuery script I did to check things on post saving.

I forgot :

```
$postForm.unbind('submit');
```